# How to create CheckerBoard with java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a checkcerboard for my lap and I'm having problems with my code.

```
int rr = 18;
int cc = 16;
for (int j= 0; j<=cc; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i<=rr; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(design);

        }
        System.out.print( design);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows = 8;
        int columns = 8;
        String sign = "*";

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(sign);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```